# rails checkbox select using link

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Hello i am using two checkbox with the each loop and using javascript i want to change the value of the checkbox.
The checkbox value getting set false with the use of javascript.but after clicking it it getting set to true but check sign is dot getting displayed on the checkbox.
here is the javascript code:

```
$(".sp-modal-content a.btn-icon").each(function(){
  console.log($(this));
  $(this).click(function(){
    ($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val());
    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked"))
    {
      alert("true");
      $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
    }
    else {
      alert("false");
        alert($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val());
          $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked" ,"checked");

    }

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using prop in place of attr might solve the problem

```
 $(".sp-modal-content a.btn-icon").each(function(){
  console.log($(this));
  $(this).click(function(){
    ($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val());
    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked"))
    {
      alert("true");
      $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
    }
    else {
      alert("false");
        alert($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val());
          $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked" ,true);

    }

  })
})
```

And also I guess you are trying to toggle the checkbox on click 
This might be shorter way. I haven't tested it though.

```
$(".sp-modal-content a.btn-icon").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    element = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    previousValue = element.attr('checked')
    element.prop('checked', !previousValue) 
  })
})
```

Comment: @dhruvmehta could you please accept this answer then?